# ERROR SIGNAL IR EN FORMULARIO WFORMS CLIENTE

Tags: c#, windows-forms, webforms, signalr

soy nuevo en cuando a programación en c# necesitaba hacer un chat entre web y windows forms por lo que investigando pude de cierta forma lograrlo que los mensajes que se envian desde el formulario de windows forms se inserten dentro de la web, sin embargo, cuando el formulario de windows requiere mostrar los mensajes me salta un error en el listbox el cual no estoy seguro como resolverlo.

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'lstMessage' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.'*

[image: Vista desde web]

[image: Formulario Windows Forms]

Les adjunto el codigo de windows forms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs;



namespace WinFormClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        HubConnection hubConnection;
        IHubProxy hubProxy;
       

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:44306/signalr/hubs/");
            hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myChatHub");
            hubProxy.On<string>("newMessageReceived", (message) => lstMessage.Items.Add(message));   
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hubProxy.Invoke("BroadcastMessageToAll", textBox1.Text).Wait();
        }
```

El html de WebForms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://localhost:44306/signalr/hubs/" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var myChatHub = $.connection.myChatHub;
            myChatHub.client.newMessageReceived = function (message) {
                $('#ulChatMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
            }
            $.connection.hub.url = "https://localhost:44306/signalr/hubs/";
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
                    myChatHub.server.broadcastMessageToAll($('#txtEnterMessage').val(), 'Web user');
                });
            }).fail(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });;
            
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="lblEnterMessage">Enter Message: </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEnterMessage" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send Message" />
        <ul id="ulChatMessages"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y por ultimo el HUB

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ChatWeb
{
    public class MyChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessageToAll(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.newMessageReceived(message);
        }

        public void JoinAGroup(string group)
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        }

        public void RemoveFromAGroup(string group)
        {
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        }

        public void BroadcastToGroup(string message, string group)
        {
            Clients.Group(group).newMessageReceived(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Si me podrian ayudar se los agradeceria muchisimo, de antemano muchas gracias